# SCP error: Bad configuration option: PermitLocalCommand

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

When I execute this command below:

```
scp -P 36000  hdfs@192.168.0.114:~/tmp.txt SOQ_log.txt
```

I get an error:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: PermitLocalCommand
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you confirm that it is exactly the command now in your question that gives you that error? And that it is not the command as it was before you edited your question that gave you the error? And that the error does not have the misspelling that appeared in the original command before you edited it?

Comment: @dave4420 yeah,it's exactly the command now in this question give that error,not the one before.

Comment: Is `scp` a shell alias or a shell function (check the output of `type -t scp`) that calls the real `scp`? Or is `scp` a shell script that calls the real `scp` (check output of `type -p scp`)? Does `PermitLocalCommand` appear in your `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (perhaps with different capitalisation)?

Comment: @dave4420 Thanks.I check type -p scp,it refer to /usr/bin/scp and thers is no PermitLocalCommand in ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: Ah, I have no idea what is causing the error then.

Comment: Just a quick untested thought: `PermitLocalCommand` defaults to 'no'.  did you enable `PermitLocalCommand` in your `~/.ssh/config` or similar file?

Answer (score 4):

`scp` runs a copy of the `ssh` program to create the communications channel, and it runs ssh with the options:

```
-oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes
```

So that explains where the "PermitLocalCommand" option is coming from in the first place. I'll add that `sftp` uses the same options to run ssh, so it'll probably display the same behavior.

"PermitLocalCommand" is normally a valid ssh configuration option. If your copy of ssh is complaining about it, then it seems that your copy of ssh isn't the normal copy of ssh that goes with your copy of scp.

[This serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/92321/debian-permit-local-command-issue) suggests that the error could be due to someone installing a malware version of `ssh` (ie, a rootkit) on your system. [This forum thread](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1132387) also suggests that the problem is due to having an altered version of `ssh`, which was fixed by removing and reinstalling the OpenSSH client utilities.

An alternate explanation would be that someone--maybe your Linux distro maintainer--has installed a version of ssh on your system with that option removed, and you're using it unawares. Or you have a very old version of the `ssh` program for some reason, which doesn't support the option.

Answer (score 1):

My system is CentOs 5.9

I'm facing the same problem, I found it to be due to this configuration line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /opt/libexec/sftp-server
```

But I cannot run /opt/libexec/sftp-server, it is broken for some reason

now it is solved by reinstall the remote openssh-server:

```
yum erase openssh-server
yum install openssh-server
```

now the changes to

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

and /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server is runnable

don't forget to execute:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: I did encounter this issue at work with one of our somewhat dated Debian server which incidentally was recently noticed to be compromised with a monero miner. Uninstalling and re-installing openssh-server really worked. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes command cannot parse this kind of stuff

:~/

Id change it to the full path.

Comment: Specifically I mean the tilda